# C# Rest Webservice with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#

I created a Rest Webservice with ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application. If I want to consume the service and send a request including a requestbody the input parameter CoreMessage item is always null. I watched some sample tutorials and some sample code but I couldn't fix the bug.

Some code of my Rest Client

```
        CoreMessage message = new CoreMessage() { Source = "Dummy", Date = DateTime.Now, Data = "abcd" };
        var url = "http://localhost:12294/api/message";
        var method = "POST";
        string reponseAsString = "";
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = method;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
            {
                writer.Write(message);  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            reponseAsString += "ERROR: " + ex.Message;
        }
```

My Controller with the Post function look like this

```
public MessageRepository repository = new MessageRepository();

        public HttpResponseMessage PostMessage(CoreMessage item)
        {
            bool status = repository.TransmitMessage(item);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.Created, status);

            return response;
        }
```

My Model

```
public class CoreMessage
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the `ContentType` of your service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things to try

First, put `[FromBody]` attribute:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostMessage([FromBody] CoreMessage item)
```

Then try to add `Content-Type` header to your request

```
request.ContentType = "application/json; chatset=utf-8"
```

And you have to make it JSON before writing to stream, you cannot write the object out like that. The method depends on what framework you use for JSON serialisation. One of the most popular one is JSON.NET, which is dead easy to install through NuGet package manager. Once you got it installed you can serialise your CoreMessage to string like:

```
string messageString = JSONConvert.SerializeObject(message);
```

Then writing it in UTF-8 encoding:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.Write(messageString);
}
```

After all, if it's still not working, you can try [Dev HTTP Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) in Chrome. The tool will allow you to craft raw HTTP request. Your request should have `Content-Type` as `application/json; charset=utf-8` and POST data as JSON string.

Comment: First of all...thanks for your response! I downloaded Json.net and added a reference of the newtonsoft.json.dll but unfortunately Visual Studio says that JsonConvert does not exist in the current context and the intellicense of VS make no offer to import a specific json "using".